# Spelling mistake in API Documentation's "Authentication" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Can you find the spelling mistake in "Unregistered Users" (**last section**) of [the **Authentication** page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)?

In case you're not in the mood for games, here is it:

> [image: screenshot]

This is actually a correct spelling - of the *wrong word.*

The correct spelling of the *intended* word is:

> [image: img]

Comment: Maybe they don't mind all scrapers, just the pugnacious ones?

Comment: Funny, I was leaning more toward *inutile*.... But I suppose a nonfunctional one would be less of a problem than a combatant one. (btw you spoiled the spoiler.)